# SQL Server XP_READREG - Read default key value

Tags: sql-server

I've used `XP_READREG` to read registry keys before and it's worked great.  Now I need to read the default value for a key. What is the syntax to read "(Default)" from a registry key?

I have tried setting `@value_name` to `''` or `'.'` or `'(Default)'` without success.

I can run the query without `@value_name` and I get back  `KeyExist = 1` indicating that the rootkey and key point correctly.

This is the general query that I'm using:

```
DECLARE @RegLoc VARCHAR(100)
select @RegLoc='TypeLib\{4BF5E120-AE37-4090-A83F-A1A8A5228371}\1.0\0\win64'

EXEC [master].[dbo].[xp_regread]    @rootkey='HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT',
                                    @key=@RegLoc,
                                    @value_name=''
```

Comment: Tried passing `NULL` ?

Comment: @Alex K., That was the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK, @Alex K. pointed out the trick in the comment to the question, pass null for @value_name.  I originally tried omitting it but the proc then defaults to an exists tests.  Explicitly passing null causes xp_regread to return a registry keys default value.  Like this:

```
DECLARE @RegLoc VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ValueName varchar(100)  -- leave this unassigned to get the default value

select @RegLoc='TypeLib\{4BF5E120-AE37-4090-A83F-A1A8A5228371}\1.0\0\win64'


EXEC [master].[dbo].[xp_regread]    @rootkey='HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT',
                                    @key=@RegLoc,
                                    @value_name = @ValueName
```